# Automatically find a given number of colors which match to each other

Tags: algorithm, colors, color-scheme

Given a number n, what is the best way to find n colors which match to each other in an harmonic way? My current approach is as follows:

- In the HSV model I start with a color color1 = (h1,s1,v1).
- For assigning the next colour (i=2, ... n) I choose: colori = ((360/n)*(i/2)+180*(i%2), s1, v1)

So, I divide the hue circle into n segments and select for each of the segments the color. When grouping the colors in the list I pair two colors which are located opposite in the hue circle with each other.

Is there any algorithm offering a better (i.e., more harmonic) choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for "color palette generation algorithm". The first result googling that is a good intro: http://devmag.org.za/2012/07/29/how-to-choose-colours-procedurally-algorithms/, but there are zillions of ways to do it, depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a great overview article. I guess I will try the triad mixing and try some customizations to get a set of visually different colors.